# always rotate an object up in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I am not good at 3d calculation, and I need help here.

I have an earth, which is a sphere in my scene, and I am using OribitControl to "rotate" it (actually OribitControl rotates camera).

I need a function, something would like `rotateUp(rad)` to rotate the earth up, no matter what's the position of camera.

The problem is, my rotateUp now is:

```
earth.rotation.x -= rad
```

This would rotate earth up if camera in the initial position, but if camera rotate 180 deg, this `rotateUp` function would actually rotates the earth down.

How to implement this function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself:

```
function rotateUp (rad) {
  const v = new THREE.Vector3()
  v.setFromMatrixColumn(camera.matrix, 0 )
  v.multiplyScalar(-rad)
  earth.rotation.x += v.x
}
```